# Port is not showing output

Tags: assembly, intel, 8051

I made a program for intel 8051 in assembly. The program compiles fine, executes fine in the simulator but it doesn't show any output on the port. The output port is just empty.

Here is the code:

```
ORG 00H

MOV P1, #00H
MOV P2, #00H
MOV P3, #00H
mov R4, #00h

TakeInput:

MOV R3,#0H


JB P3.4, TakeOperation   
DJNZ R3,TakeInput

MOV R0, P1

MOV R1, P2

MOV P2, #00H
```

TakeOperation:

```
mov p2,#00h

jb p3.5,CheckFunction

sjmp TakeOperation

CheckFunction:

mov P3,#00h
Mov R5,P2
CJNE R5,#02H,ADDT

ajmp end

ADDT:

MOV A,R0

ADD A, R1

MOV P3, A    
SJMP CheckFunction
```

What am I doing wrong that the output is not displayed at the port?
Regards

Comment: What are you inputting on ports P2 and P3? Also, what's with the convoluted way of implementing an infinite loop with `MOV R3,#0` / `DJNZ R3,TakeInput` instead of using `SJMP TakeInput` ?

Answer (score 0):

To compare two `Rx` registers:

```
MOV A,R0
CJNE A,01h,r0_r1_not_equal  ; Assumes that you're using register bank 0
; take action based on R0==R1
; ...
SJMP done
r0_r1_not_equal:
; take action based on R0!=R1  
; ...
done:
```

Comment: and why is the output not displayed on the port